# Live USB boots to black screen after grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, laptop

I created a Ubuntu USB using rufus so that i can install Ubuntu on my Acer One 10 laptop/tablet convertible. The first time I booted using the USB i tried Ubuntu without installing to make sure it worked correctly, and it did, except for the keyboard. Then i shut it down, and booted it back up to actually install Ubuntu; the keyboard still didn't work, so i got up to plug in a separate keyboard, and I dropped it and the USB came out in the middle of the installation process. Now I can't get past the grub menu. I have tried it with 2 other USB's, and my sister's computer (same model), re-downloaded the ISO and re-imaged all three USB's several times, trying to troubleshoot the issue. The screen still just goes black after selecting an option from the grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

As you were not able to complete the installation process. Try reinstalling it by USB, grub won't work as the OS is currently not installed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this has only been happening when i try to reinstall it by USB. Without the USB, my computer just boots to the EFI shell.

Comment: Try installing the Ubuntu while you use it.. (While trying it live)

Comment: Trying it live without installing also goes to a black screen. Every option on the grub menu only brings up a black screen.

Comment: Will you also post the screenshots.. For the same

Comment: sorry for the late reply

Comment: Which version ate you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04, its the version i have had the most success with.

Comment: Try formatting the partition by gparted and then install fresh..

Answer (score 0):

The grub menu has three options "try ubuntu without installing", "install ubuntu", and "check disk for errors", and all three of them only boot to a black screen.[image]

Without the USB, it just boots to this EFI shell:[image]